# Liaison after verbs

Tags: verbes, oral, liaisons

J'ai appris que on ne peut pas faire la liaison après les verbes conjugués, sauf avec les verbes *être* et *avoir*. Mais  Wikipédia [ne dit pas ça](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28linguistique%29).

Est-ce-qu'on peut faire la liaison, par exemple, avec « je voudrais une voiture » ou « tu aimes à ta mère » ? Je pense que je n'ai jamais entendu ça mais je ne suis pas sûr.

---

I was taught once that liaison after conjugated verbs is strictly prohibited, with the only exception being after the forms of *être* and *avoir.* But the Wikipedia [doesn't mention this](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28linguistique%29).

Can one make a liaison in, for instance, "je voudrais une voiture" or "tu aimes à ta mère?" I don't think I have ever heard one.

Comment: merci des corrections !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cette page de Wikipédia que tu cites me semble un peu complexe. Je te propose plutôt celle du [Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm), en plus avec des fichiers sons, et aussi celle-ci d'[Études littéraires](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/regles-de-liaison.php).

« Je voudrais une voiture » : la liaison peut se faire, elle est facultative. C'est à dire que la faire n'est pas une faute. Peut-être la fera-t-on plus facilement en lisant qu'en parlant.

Avec <strike>tu aimes à ta mère ?</strike>  le problème est différent car ça ne se dit ni ne s'écrit.

- Tu aimes ta mère.
- T'aimes ta mère  ?

Voici un cas intéressant :
« Tu les aimes à la coque ? » : je ne ferais pas la liaison entre le *s* de *aimes* et le *à*, mais entre le *m* de *aimes* et la voyelle qui suit : */tyle'zemala'kɔk/*.
De même :  */il.lə'mɑ̃,ʒɑ̃ʁɔ̃'del/*, quand je le dis, pourrait aussi bien s'écrire « Il le mange en rondelles » que « Ils le mangent en rondelles ».

Comment: « *aimes à* » prononcé [ɛ.ma] au lieu de [ɛm.a], ce n'est pas une liaison : il n'y a pas de son supplémentaire, juste un report d'une syllabe à l'autre. Pareil pour l'autre exemple.